# missing 2 required positional arguments: 'm' and 'a'

Tags: python

Tengo que hacer un programa que valide fechas contenidas en un fichero.
Primero he escrito la función que comprueba que una fecha es válida

```
def comprobar_fecha(d, m, a):

    dias_mes = [31, 28, 31, 30,31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

 
 #Aquí compruebo si el año es bisiesto para sumarle un día más a febrero

    if((a%4 == 0 and a%100 != 0) or a%400 == 0):
        dias_mes[1] += 1
 
   #Aquí veo si el mes introducido es válido o no

    if(m < 1 or m > 12):
        return False
     
 #Comprobar que el dia sea valido

    m -= 1
    if(d <= 0 or d > dias_mes[m]):
        return False
 
  #Si pasa todas las condiciones la fecha es válida

    return True
```

El problema está en que no sé cómo hacer que lea las fechas del fichero una a una y que muestre por pantalla las fechas que son válidas y las que no.
Yo había puesto:

```
def main():

    fichero_inicial = input("Escribe el nombre del fichero con la información: ")
                         
    try:
        f = open(fichero_inicial, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    except:
        print("Error en la apertura de alguno de los dos ficheros")
    else:
        correcta = f.read()
        
        
        if comprobar_fecha (correcta):
            print("Es correcta")
        else:
            print("No es correcta")
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

Pero me sale este error:

```
 comprobar_fecha() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'm' and 'a'
```

Comment: Defines `def comprobar_fecha(d, m, a):`, y luego lo llamas pasándole un parámetro -> `if comprobar_fecha (correcta):`, obviamente te faltan `m` y `a`

Comment: ¿Nos darías un ejemplo de como son las fechas en tu fichero porfavor?

Comment: Las fechas del fichero son por ejemplo: 27/11/2019

Comment: @anonymous Python no separara los elementos de la fecha magicamente pot lo que tienes que hacerlo por ejemplo usando split: `for line in f.readlines(): d, m, a = line.split("/") comprobar_fecha(d, m, a)`

Comment: Nunca jamas usar `readlines` pa leer un archivo porque lo carga todo en memoria. Si el archivo es grande, el uso de memoria es infinito

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow c:
En lugar de crear una funcion para comprobar fechas, ¿que tal si usas algo ya creado?. Hay un modulo en python que ya viene incluido para trabajar con fechas. Usandolo, podrías validar fechas con el siguiente codigo.

```
from datetime import date

def valida_fecha(fecha):
    try:
        #divido la fecha en dia, mes y año, luego transformo los tres a int y paso los argumentos a la funcion 'date' en el orden año, mes, dia.
        date(*reversed(tuple(map(int, fecha.split("/")))))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print(valida_fecha("12/02/2020"))
```

ADVERTENCIA: El código de arriba solo funcionará si la fecha es de formato 'dia/mes/año'.